# Adaptive height of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently working on a timeline using slick slider and I'm trying to find a way to make the vertical line for each child of the timeline to change in height depending on the height of the text.

You can find my current timeline at the bottom of this page: [Timeline Link](http://insight.dev.plx.mk/about/)

```html
<?php if ( have_rows('timeline_repeater') ): ?>
<div class="time-line-wrapper wrapper">
  <?php while ( have_rows('timeline_repeater') ) : the_row(); ?>
    <div class="time-line-single">
      <div class="image">
        <?php $img = get_sub_field('image'); ?>
        <img src="<?= $img['url']; ?>" alt="<?= $img['alt']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="year">
        <span class="year-span"><?php the_sub_field('year'); ?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <h3>
          <?php the_sub_field('h3'); ?>
        </h3>
        <?php the_sub_field('content'); ?>
      </div>
      <div class="line-detail">
        <div class="vertical-line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

```js
$('.time-line-wrapper').slick({
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  infinite: false
});

$(window).on('setPosition', function(event, slick) {
  slick.$slides.css('height', slick.$slideTrack.height() + 'px');
});
```

Comment: And the problem/question is?

Comment: You should also include screen shots if you want to show some design. When the web site you've linked to gets a redesign, or suddenly stops working, the question will be very unclear for future visitors.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried a fiddle using his design! Hopefully, that would help !

Answer (score 0):

We can set a specific line height when number of characters reach certain number.
In this example, I set height to 50px when we cross limit of 150 characters.

We need to loop through all timelines and do the following :

```
$.each( $( ".time-line-single" ), function() {
    var cnt =  $( this ).find("p").text().length;
    if (cnt > 150) {
    $( this ).find(".vertical-line").css("height", "50px"); 
        }
});
```

A fiddle using your code : https://jsfiddle.net/dtswq9k6/

You can paste the code above in your browser console to see the change ! Using my Laptop screen, it works best when we limit 150 chracters and set 50px as a new height.

You could alternatively use php to force styling on that element in the loop!

```
  <div class="line-detail">
    <div class="vertical-line" <?php echo (strlen(get_sub_field('content')) > 150) ? 'style="height:50px;"' :''; ?>></div>
  </div>
```